# Limit problem without l'Hopital's rule

Tags: limits

The problem goes :
Solve the following limit without using l'hopital's rule :
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}.$$
I've tried multiplying with conjugate "$x+\sin(x)$", I've tried extracting $x$ from the numerator, and I always end up in a dead end. Pleas help.

Comment: To preempt answers that try to sneak in the derivative other ways: can you use power series approximations? I.e., $\sin x = x - x^3/3! + O(x^5)$?

Comment: It is often included as a theorem or fact that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$, frequently at the same time or just before L'Hopital's rule is introduced.  Do you have access to that result?  In *Calculus 7th ed.* by Larson, Hostetler, and Edwards, this result appears as theorem 1.9 on page 63.  L'Hopital's rule is not introduced until page 531.

Comment: This seems like a farce of a problem. If Taylor approximations are available, this automatically gives L'Hopital's rule as a consequence with very little extra work. If Taylor AND L'Hoptial are not allowed, how can one proceed?

Answer (score 3):

Just expand $\sin(x)$ in a power series and you are done:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3} =
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x-(x-x^3/3!+\mathcal{O}(x^5))}{x^3} 
=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (1/3!+\mathcal{O}(x^2))
=1/6
$$

Comment: Taylor is equivalent to L'Hôpital.

Answer (score 2):

I offer an alternative route based on a trigonometric identity.

*You will need to prove that the limit $L$ exists.*

Put $x=3u$ in $$L = \lim_{x\to0}{\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}}$$

to get

$$L = \lim_{u\to 0}{\frac{3u-\sin(3u)}{(3u)^3}}$$

and since $$\sin(3u)=-4\sin^3 u + 3\sin u$$

we get 
$$\begin{align}
L = \lim_{u\to 0}{\frac{3u-(-4\sin^3 u + 3 \sin u)}{27u^3}} &= \lim_{u\to 0}{\left\{\frac{4}{27}\cdot\left(\frac{\sin u}{u}\right)^3 + \frac{u-\sin u}{9u^3}\right\}} \\\\
&= \frac{4}{27}\left(\lim_{u\to 0}{\frac{\sin u}{u}} \right)^3 + \frac{1}{9}\left(\lim_{u\to 0}{\frac{u-\sin u}{u}}\right) \\\\
&= \frac{4}{27}\cdot1 + \frac{1}{9}L\qquad(\textit{if given }\lim_{u\to 0}{\frac{\sin u}{u}} = 1)
\end{align}$$

So $$\frac{8}{9}L=\frac{4}{27} \implies L = \frac{9}{8}\cdot\frac{4}{27} = \frac{1}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have using integration by parts

$$\sin(x)=\int_0^x\cos(t)dt=x-\int_0^x(x-t)\sin(t)dt$$
and by integrating twice by parts we get
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^3}{6}\sin(t)dt$$
Finally since
$$\left|\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^3}{6}\sin(t)dt\right|\le \int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^3}{6}dt=\frac{x^4}{24}$$
we get easily the desired limit $\frac16$.

**Remark :** This method is in fact the proof of the Taylor series of the function $\sin$ with integral remainder.

Comment: Are you disguising Taylor?

Comment: Yes I'm, Isn't this allowed?

Comment: Well, Taylor is equivalent to L'Hôpital.